How to make TeX Live fonts available?
I am running Debian and I have installed the package texlive-fonts-extra which contains the Adobe font SourceCodePro:
# dpkg -S /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro
texlive-fonts-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro
# find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro 
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Bold.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-ExtraLight.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-MediumIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-BlackIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-ExtraLightIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Semibold.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-LightIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Black.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-RegularIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Light.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-BoldIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-SemiboldIt.otf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Medium.otf

But this font is not available to my system, because fc-list does not show it:
# fc-list : file | grep SourceCodePro

How to make it available?

This makes it available but just for a single user.

Create the directory ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d.

Add the file 99-texlive.conf:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
</fontconfig>


Run the command fc-cache -f -v.


